# MAVEN profiles for an Android Build

Tags: android, maven

I have the following profile included in my pom.xml file. Is this correct ? Should this profile exclude the resources based on the profile ? What am i doing wrong ?

```
<profiles>
                <profile>
                    <profile>
                        <id>xhdpi</id>
                        <activation>
                            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
                        </activation>
                        <properties>
                            <build.profile.id>xhdpi</build.profile.id>
                        </properties>
                        <build>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                    <directory>res</directory>

                                    <includes>
                                        <include>drawable-xhdpi/*.*</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>drawable-hdpi/*.*</exclude>
                                        <exclude>drawable-ldpi/*.*</exclude>
                                        <exclude>drawable-mdpi/*.*</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </build>
                    </profile>
                </profile>
            </profiles>
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: Based on a specific profile include and exlcude resources. So that my final apk file is small ? Can i achieve this with the profile ?